# Office.js Word - window.external.RegisterEvent is not a function

Tags: ms-office, office-js, word-addins

I am developing a Word 2016 Addin and I have received an error from a client (logged via [Sentry](https://sentry.io)) that I'm having trouble reproducing. It occurred in a Dialog window on macOS Sierra 10.12.6 in Word 16.11.

```
window.external.RegisterEvent is not a function.
(In 'window.external.RegisterEvent(n,t,i,r)', 'window.external.RegisterEvent' is undefined)
```

The error originated from the word API script `https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/word-mac-16.00.js` and looking at the debug code on Github, it appears to be coming from [this line](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/blob/release/dist/word-mac-16.00.debug.js#L4365).

**Does anyone have any insight into why this may be occurring?** It hasn't happened on any other platform and I'm having trouble reproducing it locally.

Thanks in advance. I'm happy to provide more information if required.

**NOTE**: *This error occurred during the Addin submission review process causing a failed submission - hence the need to track down the source.*

Comment: No thoughts on this? Let me know if there is any other information that might be helpful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reported this issue here https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/97 which was related to the dialog API. Seems that window.external.registerEvent is missing in the dialog on Mac.
I could fix it with the following hack which should be called after office.js. Maybe you have the same problem.

```
const isMac = !!navigator.platform && 
navigator.platform.toUpperCase().indexOf('MAC') >= 0;

if (isMac && window.external && !window.external.RegisterEvent) {
    window.external.RegisterEvent = () => { };
}
```

Comment: Thanks Baris - appreciate the response. I’ll try your solution out.